# IOException in GAE 1.7.4

Tags: android, google-app-engine, ioexception

I have a problem to send data from my gae-server to the client. Everything works in local environment, but not on Google`s server environment I get an IOException.

First of all I send a json file to my  gae server...

```
url = new URL("http://xxxserver.appspot.com/xxxserver")
               HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
           connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
           connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
           connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + json.toString().getBytes("UTF8").length);
           connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  
           connection.setUseCaches (false);
           connection.setDoInput(true);
           connection.setDoOutput(true);    
           connection.setConnectTimeout(40000); //40 seconds
```

the json-string, whick should send back is created correctly. it looks like follows:

```
{"location1 cost_char":"0.77","location1 cost_reim":"0.0","location2 dist":"34.02","location1 dist":"2.76"}
```

The server receive the file, creates the json-string correctly, but then crashes with an IOException when it should flush the json-string back:

```
//Send data to server
    try {   
    resp.setContentLength(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8").length);
    resp.setContentType("application/json");
        Writer wr = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter (resp.getOutputStream()));           
         try {
             wr.write(json.toString());
             wr.flush();        //crash!!!!!!!!!!!!!
         } 
         finally {
             if (wr != null)
                    logger.info(TAG +"test6");
                 wr.close();
         }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.info(TAG +": IO Error");
        String temp = getStackTrace (e);
    logger.warning(TAG +": Exception is: " +temp);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {   
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.warning(TAG +": Exception is: " +e);
    }
```

client to receive data:

```
//Get response from server
            try {
                InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader (connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(is);  //BufferedInputStreams works on byte streams.  BufferedReaders works on character streams.
                String line;
                response = new StringBuffer();     
               try {
                   while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                       response.append(line);
                       Log.d(TAG, "Received Data: " +line);
                   }
                   Log.v("Abrage:" ,"data received");
               }
               finally {
                   if (rd != null)
                       rd.close();
               }
```

Here is the StackTrace:

```
com.lemtex.carpoolio.server.CarpoolioServerServlet doPost: CarpoolioServerServlet: Exception is: java.io.IOException: Closed
at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.write(AbstractGenerator.java:629)
at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractGenerator$Output.write(AbstractGenerator.java:579)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:220)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:290)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:294)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:140)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:253)
at com.lemtex.carpoolio.server.CarpoolioServerServlet.doPost(CarpoolioServerServlet.java:387)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:466)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:473)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:694)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:470)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I solved my problem.. I closed the OutputStream with
`resp.getOutputStream().close();`before the data was sent....

Answer (score 0):

```
resp.setContentLength(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8").length);
```

might not be the same length as what you are sending with `.toString()`, especially if it isn't pure ASCII, which I am guessing you are sending extended characters outside the ASCII set.

```
wr.write(json.toString());
```

and the server is probably closing the connection before the entire string is written.
either get the actual length of the `String` or send the `.getBytes("UTF8")` version you are getting the length of. You can't do it half and half like you are doing.

You don't show enough code to actually diagnose the problem, all we can do is guess.

Comment: i changed it to (I made the same mistake, when sending json to the server): resp.setContentLength(json.toString().length() but the IOException problem still exists. also   resp.getOutputStream().write(json.toString().getBytes());
        resp.getOutputStream().flush(); doesn`t work. On local environment everything works fine.